# Why prestashop emails wot working even after configuring SMTP?

Tags: smtp, prestashop

After the transfert of my website from one host to another, the website don't send emails anymore.
I've configured SMTP and when I send a test email it works fine.

But unfortunately it still doesn't send any emails

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases: You have to use localhost instead of server or IP address